# Is using mysqli_query() dangerous if no user input is considered in the query?

Tags: php, mysql

Whenever I want to run a MySQL query, I prepare my statements:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = ?";
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($con);
$stmt->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['user']);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$assoc = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
```

But what if I'm not accepting any information from the user, at all? Is this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users";
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($con);
$stmt->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$assoc = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
```

Just as safe as:

```
$assoc = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users"));
```

Keeping in mind, a user could have still entered an SQLi statement earlier, when creating an account, and now I'm selecting it without preparing it.

What if I'm just selecting a column that only stores numbers (datatype is double):

```
$assoc = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con, "SELECT version FROM users ORDER BY version LIMIT 1"))[0];
```

Comment: Since there's no user input, it's not dangerous. However, if you perform that query frequently - using a prepared statement is slightly faster (for repeated queries) because MySQL doesn't have to lex the query over and over again every time. However, for such a simple query we're probably talking about microseconds of optimization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally binding variables with PDO has been the best approach for a consistent, I-don't-have-to-think-about-injection development.

When you control the query fully there's no reason you need to prepare it except for making yourself habitually exposed to good practices at all times.

As a side-note I would avoid using * in any production code and specify the fields you want explicitly.

I would scrub your current user-inputted data to avoid any worries about what could have been entered in the past.

Comment: So injection can only happen during insertion, not when retrieving rows that have injection characters in them?

Comment: Injection can happen any time malicious code is forced-in to a server to be parsed and executed.  I would agree with Vladimir's answer and use PDO.

Comment: After ensuring no future unwanted user input can get into my database I would clean-scrub any potential "bad" data to be clean so that I don't have to worry about protection from my own side in addition to the users. I can't think of anything that a user can insert into a database that will blow up your application with a SELECT statement. Speaking of injection. Examples posted somewhere else a moment ago: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_SQL_Injection_%28OTG-INPVAL-005%29

Answer (score 0):

It would be dangerous if you were to use the returned data in another query, unprepared. As you have it I don't see a danger.

For example

```
$query = "SELECT email FROM useremails";
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($con);
$stmt->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$assoc = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$query = "SELECT email FROM users where email = '" . $assoc['email'] . "'";
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($con);
$stmt->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
```

That could cause an injection if the email column had malicious data in it.

Comment: So SQLi can occur when inserting into OR selecting from?

Comment: See this link for injection examples: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_SQL_Injection_%28OTG-INPVAL-005%29

Comment: Injection can occur at any level. You should always abstract your queries from user inputted data. In your example it wont affect anything because the injected data isn't going into the SQL it is just being returned to the PHP.